# How to modify VSCode Activity Bar from Source Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm customizing VSCode and I need to modify Activity Bar, removing some icon and add one more icon to open extension which is now triggered by keyboard shortcut.

Does anybody have idea how to modify VSCode source code to accomplish that?

Is there any document helping me understand the source code of VSCode?

If anyone can provide any clues, such as modifying the address of the source code, I would be very grateful

Comment: you mean you're forking VS Code, basically? or just writing an extension?

Comment: you remove/hide icons by right-click, you add icons with an extension

Comment: I am forking VS Code,

Comment: I do wonder why what rioV8 suggested doesn't work for your use-case though. please explain. or does it actually work for your use-case?

Comment: sorry, My English is poor, this is my first question. I am trying to develop a version of the vscode browser, so I want to remove some features in activityBar from source code, Not as a user. 
This may mean that I must familiarize myself with the vscode source code